# Naming an objects "instantiator" object

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, naming

sorry I'm having a brain freeze and not even sure how to phrase the question correctly on this one.
Trying to figure out how I would refer to the object that my subject was instantiated in
e.g.:

```
class Foo
{
    private Bar m_bar;

    public void InstantiateMyBar()
    {
        m_bar = new Bar();
    }
}

Foo fooObj = new Foo();
foo.InstantiateMyBar();

print("A *Bar* object was instantiated in *fooObj*.");
print("*fooObj* is that *Bar* object's ... ?");
```

I'm preferably looking for something short and simple like "parent object", but I guess that could cause confusion with inheritance.

Comment: Wouldn't naming be more of convention in your team/group. Thought it might be equally good to call it a creator or builder object.

Comment: Owner, container, parent, doesn't really matter what you call it.

Comment: Thanks, those are all good suggestions. I only thought of owner and parent and wasn't sure I was happy with either of them.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo` has a field of type `Bar`, but not vice versa. `Bar` has no information about which object it's instantiated in. You can add a `Parent` property to `Bar` and assign it to `Foo`, then you will have a reference both ways.

```
public void InstantiateMyBar()
{
    m_bar = new Bar { Parent = this };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The question is really only about how to call it or refer to it in communication, so naming in a sense, although I'm not trying to name a variable here.For example if I talk about a base class, it's very clear right away what I'm talking about.